# Appropriate data structure for int, int & string

Tags: java, data-structures

I am hesitating what is the suitable data structure to save the following data form:

1. an integer represents min number
2. an integer represents max number
3. a string contains a message

So that if I have a result_number I can -

1. check if result_number lies between the min & max number
2. and display the corresponding message

So what is the appropriate data structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number of intervals is small, use a `class` with three members (`min`, `max`, and `message`), store them in a list, and run a linear search.

If the number of intervals is overwhelming, and the timing requirements make linear search prohibitive, create an [*interval tree*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree), ans associate the messages with its leaf nodes.

If the intervals are not overlapping, you can create an interval class with two ends, and store interval objects in a `TreeMap` using their left boundary to compare intervals. With this `TreeMap` in hand, you can find an interval quickly by calling [`floorEntry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#floorEntry%28K%29) on the number that you are trying to locate and checking if the returned interval key overlaps the value that you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I was actually looking for a ready-made java data structure like: Maps, Set, hashTable,...etc. Is there any such kind of data structure?

Comment: @WaelShowair There is a relatively easy solution for non-overlapping intervals (see my edit) but there is nothing for the general case as far as I know.

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you want...

(Wait for it...)

... a class with two integers and a string.

```
public final class RangeValidation {
    private final int minimum;
    private final int maximum;
    private final String message;

    public RangeValidation(int minimum, int maximum, String message) {
        if (minimum > maximum) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid min/max combination");
        }
        if (message == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        this.minimum = minimum;
        this.maximum = maximum;
        this.message = message;
    }

    // You can tweak this API, of course...
    // it could throw an exception instead, or return an empty string for
    // success, etc.
    public String validate(int value) {
        return value < minimum || value > maximum ? mesasge : null;
    }
}
```

Of course you may want to make this implement an interface to fit in with a more general validation framework etc... but the important point is that you've already neatly describe what you want your type to contain - so you just need to write it.

Also note that this counts the `maximum` value as *inclusive* - you may wish to make it exclusive, in order to be able to represent empty ranges. (That does make it harder to represent a range for which `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is valid though...)

Comment: why return null? Why not just return an empty string?

Comment: @MyNameIsTooCommon: Null is more of a non-value... I'd expect to check for the return being null to indicate that everything was okay, but checking against an empty string wouldn't be as nice, IMO.

Comment: @MyNameIsTooCommon returning `""` is in-band signaling (ie, magic value).

Comment: Because an empty string is still a string, and harder to detect from the calling code. Null can never be a string, therefore it cannot be a valid message. Personally, I would rather see validate() return a boolean, and the message can be retrieved for the user when necessary.

Comment: @SteveKuo: `null` is a magic value too, of course - but it's a more "known to be magic" value :)

Comment: I would throw `IllegalArgumentException` when message is null as it's an illegal argument.

Comment: @SteveKuo: It's a matter of some debate; I follow Josh Bloch's lead as per Effective Java, 2nd edition. This is also partly out of habit of using `Preconditions.checkNotNull`, effectively from Guava, at work.

Comment: In practice, either a set of validations will be performed and all validation failures accumulated---then this is the best design; or a fail-fast approach will be taken---then `validate` should throw a `ValidationFailureException`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I was actually looking for a ready-made java data structure like: Maps, Set, hashTable,...etc. Is there any such kind of data structure?

Comment: @WaelShowair: There's no indication that a collection is appropriate at all. What operations would you want to perform on such a collection? The code I've given you *exactly* satisfies your demands - why would you want to do anything more complicated with collections?

Comment: @JonSkeet, I would like to use collections because I guess it is more efficient from performance point of view

Comment: @WaelShowair: Um, what? In order to say that X is more efficient from Y, you've got to have a concrete idea of what X and Y are... just "I want to use collections because they're efficient" isn't a useful approach to problem-solving.

Answer (score 3):

In java a "data structure" is represented by a class with fields. The class may have methods that use these fields.

Try this:

```
public class MyClass {

    private int min;
    private int max;
    private String message;

    public void testNumber(int number) {
        if (number >= min && number <= max) {
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    } 
}
```

You should probably have a constructor to set the values of the fields and I would recommend making the fields `final`.